# Reading points from a Geography Polygon in a PostGIS database

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, postgis

My goal:  To read the points from a Geography Polygon stored in my PostGIS database.

The PostGIS manual has [a great example](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ch05.html#id2633989) of how to extract a Polygon from a database.

```
PGgeometry geom = (PGgeometry)r.getObject(1); 
if (geom.getType() == Geometry.POLYGON ) { 
  Polygon pl = (Polygon)geom.getGeometry(); 

  for (int r = 0; r < pl.numRings(); r++) { 
    LinearRing rng = pl.getRing(r); 
    System.out.println("Ring: " + r); 

    for (int p = 0; p < rng.numPoints(); p++ ) { 
      Point pt = rng.getPoint(p); 
      System.out.println("Point: " + p);
      System.out.println(pt.toString()); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

I am dealing with Geography, however, not Geometry, so this code does not quite work for me.  If I try to extract a Polygon from my table, I get the following `ClassCastException`:

```
org.postgresql.util.PGobject cannot be cast to org.postgis.PGgeometry
```

I've modified the first two lines to look like this, which works:

```
PGobject area = (PGobject)rs.getObject("area");
if (area.getType().compareTo("geography") == 0) {
    ...
}
```

My problem now is that I can't figure out how to modify the third line of the code sample to work for Geography.  I probably shouldn't cast it to the `Polygon` type, since that is for Geometry, but is there an equivalent for Geography?  I know that Geography is only partially supported for a lot of stuff, so I'm not sure what I can or can't do here.

Comment: Have you tried `st_geometryn` and `st_pointn`? Pseudocode: `while (st_geometryn(i)) { while (st_pointn(k)) { process_pt(); k++ } i++ }` ?

Comment: you need to cast the polygon to `GEOMETRY` from the server somehow

Comment: @bvmou: ST_GeometryN and ST_PointN only work for Geometry, whereas I am working with Geography.  I hadn't considered trying to retrieve the points on the database side, though, rather than on the Java side.  I suppose I could just do a `ST_AsText(polygon)` and parse the points out of there if I can't figure anything better out.  Still, it seems like there must be a better way of doing this through JDBC, I just don't know it.

Comment: @Mike Toews: Do I really have to cast it?  I would like to avoid that if I can, since the data could potentially not behave as expected when going over dateline, poles, and for large geometries or geometry pairs that cover more than one UTM zone.

Comment: Where GEOMETRY could misbehave (around datelines, poles, etc.) is when you try the area and length functions. I believe that the data structures are the same between the two types (i.e. 1:1), so you can always cast a GEOMETRY back to GEOGRAPHY for either storage or area/distance calculations. However, I'm no pro with the JDBC interface, so you might want to check with folks on the postgis-users mail list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up deciding to get the coordinates from Postgres using the ST_AsText() method, rather than extracting them from some sort of Geography object in Java.  Then I just parsed the polygon string in Java.

The PostgreSQL statement I executed looks like this:

```
SELECT id, name, ST_AsText(area) FROM area_table;
```

In Java I extract the String from the ResultSet after doing my JDBC query:

```
String area = rs.getString("ST_AsText");
```

And I get something that looks like this:

```
"POLYGON((-49 52,123 52,123 -4,-49 -4,-49 52))"
```

Then I just parsed the points out of that.

```
double[] bounds = new double[8];
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    String[] lonLat = points[i].split(" ");
    for (int j = 0; j < lonLat.length; j++) {
        bounds[k++] = Double.parseDouble(lonLat[j]);
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but it's the best way I could figure out on my own.

Comment: I would personally use regular expressions to get the points.

Comment: also do substring in SQL to avoid sending word "POLYGON(" for every row substring(ST_AsText(ST_Transform(l.way,4326)),'\((.+)\)') as way

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the object is a polygon, it's quite simple.

```
PGpolygon polygon = (PGpolygon)rs.getObject("area");

for (int i = 0; i < polygon.points.length; i++)
    {
    System.out.println(String.format("(%d,%d)" polygon.points[i].x, polygon.points[i].y));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PGgeometry geo = (PGgeometry)rs.getObject("coords");
Geometry poly = foo.getGeometry();
for (int i = 0; i < poly.numPoints(); i++)
{
    System.out.println("-->"+poly.getPoint(i).y+", "+ poly.getPoint(i).x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ST_AsGeoJSON, and then just parse the json:

```
SELECT id, name, ST_AsGeoJSON(area) FROM area_table;
```

Then you can get the area as json like this:

```
String area = rs.getString("area");
```

And now that you have it as geoJSON, you can parse the JSON and do what ever you wish with it.